# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected predictions to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras

I've searched several similar topics covering comparable problems. Despite this, I still haven't managed to solve my issue, why I now try to ask the community.
What I'm ultimately trying to do is to develop a model using transfer learning. I am using InceptionV3. I have freezed all the layers and added the last dense layer to predict 4 classes.
The code is:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape= (img_width, img_height, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
# # Top Model Block    
u = base_model.output
u = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(u)
u = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(u)
u = Dropout(0.5)(u)

predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(u)

model = Model(base_model.input, predictions)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Here is my code for training,

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                    epochs=nb_epoch / 5,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I am compiling using the following code,

```
model.compile(optimizer='nadam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',  
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My code for data augmentation goes like this,

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,

                                  rotation_range=transformation_ratio,
                                   shear_range=transformation_ratio,
                                   zoom_range=transformation_ratio,
                                   cval=transformation_ratio,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x_train,labels_train,batch_size=batch_size)

val_generator = validation_datagen.flow(x_val,labels_val,batch_size=batch_size)
```

Please help me debug this error.
Note: nb_classes = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the shape of your labels? I guess you haven't one-hot encoded labels_val and labels_train.

if your labels are like: [0,0,1,3,2,2,0 ....] then use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"

else apply "one-hot encoding" on your labels so this will be the mapping:

```
0 : 1 0 0 0
1 : 0 1 0 0
2 : 0 0 1 0
3 : 0 0 0 1

from keras.utils import to_categorical
labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

Comment: I just explained it